# If I Set Copy Local to false for a referenced project the main project can't find the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to develop an application that uses plugins. I have one project for the main application, one for common elements that plugins can/must use, and one for a test plugin. The main project and the test plugin project both reference the common elements. If I leave Copy Local set to true then I get three copies of the common elements (it will be worse when I have more plugins), and I think it's messing up reflection. When the main program tries to reflect on a custom attribute (defined in common) applied to a class in the test plugin using

```
Object[] attributes = pluginType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PluginAttribute), true);
```

I don't find the attribute, but when I do:

```
Object[] attributes = pluginType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

the attribute appears in the list. I'm guessing that's because because the main program and the test plugin are getting PluginAttribute from different assemblies so they're not seen as the same thing.

The solution would seem to be to turn off Copy Local. When I do that, though, I get a runtime error that the program can't find the assembly containing the common elements. How do I tell the runtime where to look for it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

Ok, here's some more detail of the scenario.

I have three projects in the solution. One is for a dll, let's call it Common, that I leave in the directory that VS chooses for it, so the dll ends up in `./Common/bin/Debug`. The dll contains definitions of an interface that all plugins should implement: something like

```
namespace Common
{
    [ContractClass(typeof(PluginContract))]
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        String Foo();
    }
}
```

It also contains definition of an attribute class that can be applied to plugins, something like:

```
public class PluginAttribute: Attribute
{
    public String Bar {get; protected set;}
    public PluginAttribute(String bar)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

The next project is the Host, which is an executable. Again, that's in the default directory, so the executable is in `./Host/bin/Debug`. That searches for assemblies in `./Host/bin/Debug/Plugins`, and uses reflection to search each assembly for classes that implement IPlugin. If it does, then I use the code I quoted above to see if it has PluginAttribute set.

The final project is a test plugin, which I have set to build to `./Host/bin/Debug/Plugins`.

```
namespace TestPlugin
{
    [PluginAttribute("Test Class")]
    public class TestClass: IPlugin
    {
        public string Foo()
        {
            return "Foo";
        }
    }
}
```

Host is finding `TestClass` in the `TestPlugin` assembly just fine, but I'm having trouble accessing the PluginAttribute. My *guess* is that this is because I have three copies of `Common.dll`, and that there's an issue with Host using the copy in `./Host/bin/Debug` but `TestClass` is presumably built with the copy in `./Host/bin/Debug/Plugins`, a physically different dll (does that make it a different assembly, or is it just another copy of the same dll?) So to follow up that guess I tried setting Copy Local to false, so I only got one copy of `Common.dll` in `./Common/bin/Debug`. That builds just fine, but gives me a runtime error that it can't load the Common assembly.

Comment: The only good explanation for this is that your PluginAttribute class appears in more than one assembly.  You'll need to fix that.  Move the class to a single assembly that all plugins reference.

Comment: I suspect that either you have two AppDomains resolving in different directories and therefore loading their own copies of the attribute, or you have a miss-behaving assembly resolver which is re-loading the assembly.
Can you provide more information on how the other assembly is being loaded?

Comment: Are you referencing different versions of this "common elements" assembly?

Comment: Hans: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. My Host class and my test plugin both reference the common dll, but Copy Local creates multiple dlls, and turning off Copy Local gives me a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell the runtime about the location of the assembly you can use the private binpath of app domain.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.appendprivatepath.aspx

Sorry I didn't get the scenario exactly what you are facing.This is just a solution to tell the assembly location.

Comment: Ok, here's some more detail of the scenario.